# Grab the location of selected node of TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

This is a theoretic question so no code (sorry for that). I want to catch the position (X an Y values) of the selected node of  TreeView control when user select that particular node. I browsed the intellisense but there are no tags like "Location" or "Position". How to achieve this? Actually I am trying to add dynamic buttons and textBox beside the selected node, so I need the position of the node.

Please Help.

Comment: @L.B Sorry I havent checked that method(Its really unpredictable). will it give the position of selected node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by using `TreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.X` (For X position) and `TreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Y` (For Y position) and Kept those dynamic Controls in a panel.

```
  int DistanceFromNode = 250;
  MyPanel.SetBounds(MyTreeview.SelectedNode.Bounds.X + DistanceFromNode,
        MyTreeview.SelectedNode.Bounds.Y, MyPanel.Width, MyPanel.Height);
```

Any other methods for approaching this are happily welcome.

Comment: If I mark this as answer, I am afraid this question will lose attention of other users. and also I think this can be approach in more efficient way... The code which I have posted has some limitations like the panel goes out of the form if the user adds multiple childs to a child node.

Comment: This is indeed the good answer. Bounds represents the item's location if it's visible or is Empty if the item is not visible.

Comment: SO is giving alert that I can accept my own answer after two days.

Comment: This is really a good answer. It solved my problem well. I wonder why there is no upvotes for it!

Answer (score 0):

That position would change when user scrolls the treeview, IMO instead of drawing at location of selected node it would be better to customize appearance of tree node in DrawNode event.

In that event you can check if node is selected and then draw additional button, this way your button will scroll with the rest of treeview.

Here is the example :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried to show a Dialog just beside a SelectedNode of TreeView control.
I solved this issue like below:

```
int x = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.X + myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Width;  
int y = myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Y + myTreeView.SelectedNode.Bounds.Height;  
Point point = new Point(x,y);   
Point absPoint = myTreeView.PointToScreen(point);

MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
dialog.Location = absPoint;
dialog.show()
```

This code display a Dialog a position of the Right_Bottom side of the selected tree node.

By Jeff